# If one button was clicked right after another - do...?

Tags: java, calculator

I'm working on Java Netbeans.

I'm making a calculator. So what I need to do is:  If user clicked on = symbol and got a result, then clicked on any number (is starting new calculation), then the program should make all values it saved 0. How can I achieve that?

How can I tell a program to do something if one button was clicked after another?

Comment: Your calculator will somehow store its *state*, here perhaps the current value saved, and perhaps it will be represented as a double. In your `=` button's button-action (not sure what GUI you're using), your control will need to tell your model to set the value state to 0. The specifics of how to do this will all depend on the code you've written so far and the structure of your program, something that we currently know nothing about.

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, thereby getting better answers.

Comment: `"How can I tell a program to do something if one button was clicked after another?"` -- again, you have the `=` button's listener change the state of the Calculator object so that its value double variable is 0. Again the details will depend on code you're not showing. Please read the links above and improve your question before it gets closed.

Answer (score -1):

When the button is clicked, create a variable that will be used to determine a true or false value. Ex:

`boolean firstButtonClicked = false;`.

Then, in your other portion of code, use an "if" statement. Ex:

`if (firstButtonClicked == true) {//run code for true value}`

`else {//run code for false value}`

You could then set the value (most likely a jTextField) to 0 to start fresh. You would put this code in the "true" value section.